# Вопрос про QuerySet. Сколько раз выполняется запрос в БД?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-model

```
query1 = Model.objects.all()
query2 = query1.exclude(id=17)
query3 = query1.distinct()
```

Сколько раз выполнится запрос в базу данных?

Comment: Здесь три раза. Надо так Model.objects.all().exclude(...).dictinct() - таким образом сформируется один запрос

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Вы говорите о формировании запроса, а у автора вопрос о выполнении )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Могу ошибаться, так как именно с django и его orm я не работал.

Но, кажется, в данном куске кода запросов к базе вообще не выполнится.

В документации читаю:

> Внутренне QuerySet может быть создан, отфильтрован, нарезан и, как правило, передан без фактического запроса к базе данных. На самом деле никаких действий с базой данных не происходит, пока вы не сделаете что-то для оценки набора запросов.

Так как, согласно той же документации, все упомянутые в вашем коде методы возвращают новый QuerySet и никак не обращаются к результату его выполнения, я делаю вывод, что реального запроса к базе не будет произведено.

Запрос будет выполнен, только когда вы начнёте как-то работать с результатом, например, сделав `list(query3)`

Comment: Да, это так, `QuerySet` ленивые и не будут выполнять запрос в БД до последнего, пока не понадобится произвести вычисления, связанные с данными